# Google Apps Script - Two functions / scripts works when ran separately but not combined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script that updates the values of an XLS file. I'll only add what I see as relevant to the problem but tell me if you need more info.

I firstly submit a Form that says what values to add, where to add it and how many.
The script then runs as the form is submitted.

It first convert the .XLS file to a .CSV file, and then add the data from the CSV file to a google spreadsheet, while also adding the values where I've told it to so everything is properly in order. All of this works fine, I can see the values have been updated in the Google Sheet each time, while it happens and after the code has run.

After I'm done, I want to convert the Google Sheet back to an XLS file, and place it back the folder where it originally was. The first time I do this the values has been updated in the XLS file, but the second time and every time after that, it "lags one session behind". The second time I don't get the updated values in the new XLS file, the third time I get the updated values from the second time, and onwards. This only happens to the XLS file, not the Google Sheet.

This does only happens when the code/function that exports the XLS file is run manually by me, it all works properly. But if i add that function after the main code the problem happen.

And I've tried to pause the code for 10 seconds between the functions, but I get the same result.

---

As all the values being added works properly in the google sheet I'll just add the code of the conversions of the filetypes. I'll just comment what happens in between with the //

Here is just the function that runs both at the same time but doesn't give me an XLS file with the latest updated values:

```
function test() {    

  newValuesToDatabase();
  updateALLITEMS();

}
```

Function that adds new values (to both an irrelevant other spreadsheet and to the spreadsheet that will become the XLS file)

```
function newValuesToDatabase() {


// FIRST FINDS OUT WHAT TO UPDATE FROM THE FORM SHEET 
// Ends up with "formX" array seen later in the code


// Opens and gets the data from another sheet I also want to update (Irrelevant sheet) 
// This ends up with the "itemDataBase" Array used later


// Gets the XLS file and turn it into CSV


    var workFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById( "(workFolderid)" ),
        backupFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById( "(backupFolderid)" );

    var oauthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById( "(sourceFolderid)" ),
        mimes = [MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY];



    for (var m = 0; m < mimes.length; m++) {

      var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(mimes[m]);

        while (files.hasNext()) {

          var sourceFile = files.next();

          if (sourceFile.getName() == "ALL ITEMS") {

            console.log("File found")


            //Creates a backupfile to be put in a different folder
            var backupDate = (new Date).getDate() + ", " 
                           + (new Date).toString().split(" ")[1] + " " 
                           + (new Date).getYear();

            sourceFile.makeCopy(backupFolder).setName("backup on " + backupDate);
            sourceFile.setTrashed(true);


            var googleSheet = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&convert=true", {
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                    payload: sourceFile.getBlob().getBytes(),
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + oauthToken
                    }
                }
            ).getContentText());   


            // The exportLinks object has a link to the converted CSV file
            var targetFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
                googleSheet.exportLinks["text/csv"], {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + oauthToken
                    }
                });

            // Save the CSV file in a folder to be deleted in the end of the script when done with it
            var csvFile = workFolder.createFile(targetFile.getBlob()).setName(sourceFile.getName() + ".csv");

          }
        }
      } 





    // Finds the google sheet that later will be converted back to XLS:


     var checkSSFile = workFolder.getFilesByName("Update Items (ikke rør)");
     var checkID = checkSSFile.next().getId().toString();

     var addSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(checkID),
         addSheet = addSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("ALL ITEMS");



     // Gets the CSV file and makes an array from it

     var csvFile = workFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV).next();

     if (csvFile.getName() == "ALL ITEMS.csv") {

       var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile.getBlob().getDataAsString());

     }



     function updateAmount() {  // ( This function is ran at the bottom of code )



       //Code first adds stuff to the irrelevant spreadsheet mentioned in the beginning of this code



       // Then gets the sheet that will be converted to XLS:

         var range = addSheet.getRange(1, 1, addSheet.getLastRow()+1, 2);
         range.clearContent(); //Empties sheet first so there are no overlap when adding everything over again


         //Code then adds the old and new values into that sheet in the right order and way

     }




   // Here is where the code is ran dependent on what the form says.


     if (formX[0][1] == "Add a new item of something we have from before") {

       updateAmount();

     } else if (formX[0][1] == "Add a completely new item") {

       //I have not added this function/code yet

     } else {

       console.log("Could not find a mode in the form submission");

     }


     csvFile.setTrashed(true); //Then trashes the csv file in the end
}
```

Then the function that converts it back and places it in the right place:

```
function updateALLITEMS() {

  var workFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById( "(workFolderid)" );
  var checkSS = workFolder.getFilesByName("Update Items (ikke rør)");
  var checkID = checkSS.next().getId().toString();

  var sourceFolder  = DriveApp.getFolderById( "(sourceFolderid)" ),
      file          = DriveApp.getFileById(checkID),
      url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+checkID+'/export?format=xlsx';
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var newAllItems      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    payload: file.getBlob().getBytes(),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
  });


  // Then add "ALL ITEMS" XLS file back to where it was
  sourceFolder.createFile(newAllItems.getBlob()).setName("ALL ITEMS"); 


   //This deletes files that appear on the main GDrive folder, don't know why. 
   //These files are named "Unknown", and are copies of the Google Sheet I'm working on

  var ss = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS); 
  while (ss.hasNext()) {
    var sht = ss.next();
    if (sht.getName() == "Untitled") {

      var shtID = sht.getId();
      var checkSht1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(shtID).getSheets();
      if ( checkSht1.length == 1 ) { 

        if (checkSht1[0].getRange(1, 1).getValue() == "BARCODE") {

          sht.setTrashed(true);


        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for reading through all that, I've been stuck with this for too long. I've tried many different things, but always get the same result (unless I manually begin one, then the other when the first is done). Hopefully the code isn't too confusing, I'm new to coding :)

Comment: Have you tried SpreadsheetApp.flush at the end of the first function?

Comment: Oh fantastic, that worked. I thought it would need something like that but I didn't quite know what it was called. Thank you! Add this as an answer and I'll vote it as being solved.

Comment: BTW if you're ever working with documents there is a saveAndClose()  function that does a similar so of thing for documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried SpreadsheetApp.flush at the end of the first function?