# Two Apps Script functions work when run consecutively, but not as one script- I can't work out the problem

Tags: google-apps-script

These 2 functions produce the results I want when I manually run one after the other, but fail to output the results whenever I try to run them together. I've tried many ways, including recording a macro calling each script in turn (as in the 2nd example). Please can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
function CountBookings2() {
  // inserts 2 columns, counts duplicate strings in column C, returns results in column D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRange('B:C').activate();
  ss.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsAfter(ss.getActiveRange().getLastColumn(), 2);
  
  ss.getRange('D2').activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=countif(C:C,C2)');
  ss.getActiveRange().autoFill(ss.getRange('D2:D156'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  ss.getRange('D:D').activate();
}

function CopyValuesOnly(){
// returns formula results from column D as values in column E 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.getRange("D:D").copyTo(ss.getRange("E1"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Example 2

```
function combined() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  CountBookings2();
  CopyValuesOnly();
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script - Two functions / scripts works when ran separately but not combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989786/google-apps-script-two-functions-scripts-works-when-ran-separately-but-not-c)

Comment: My best advice is to learn how to right code without the use of setActiveSheet() and activate() methods.